# Make all the cells textboxes of the selected row when clicking on the button

Tags: vb.net

I have a `datagridview` in my form which shows data from `CSV` file and `edit button`.

*what I want to do is*, when I click on `edit button`, All the cells of the selected row made `textboxes`.
*hope you understand my question.?*

Comment: tried anything ?? or show your code!!!

Comment: I'm assuming that you need to edit each cell when you click on `EDIT BUTTON`, If so you need not to change it to `textboxes` because a `CELL` itself allows editing so you can directly edit respective `CELL` right ??

Comment: What you want is a button that toggles whether or not the cells are read-only.

Answer (score 0):

What you've asked for is not possible.  A `DataGridView` can only actually ever contain one control at a time, for the cell you're currently editing.  What you can do is make all rows read-only by default and then, when you click the button, set the `ReadOnly` property of the appropriate row to `False` to make that row editable.  If you set the `EditMode` of the grid to `EditOnEnter` then the contents of a cell is immediately editable when that cell gets focus, just like a regular `TextBox`.  That will achieve the same result.